# Typescript and func in chrome.scripting.ScriptInjection

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

In a browser plugin, I have this:

```js
        const addEvent = (data) => {
          window.postMessage(data, '*');
        };
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
          func: addEvent,
          args: [data],
        });
```

Typscript creates with the error:

> Argument of type '{ target: { tabId: number; }; func: (data: any) =>
> void; args: MappDebugMessage[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'ScriptInjection'.   Object literal may only specify known
> properties, and 'func' does not exist in type
> 'ScriptInjection'.ts(2345)

The reason is func, of course, which was called function until Chrome 93, and Typescript doesn't know this yet. Do I have any way to tell Typescript about func, other than just add a @ts-ignore comment above that line?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by updating the @types/chrome package to the most current version.